# How to increase Spring Cloud Gateway throughput without 502 errors

Tags: load-testing, spring-cloud-gateway, reactor-netty, http-status-code-502

I am running a Spring Cloud Gateway(version 3.0.3) Project with reactor netty(version 2.5.7). My system is with 8 core processor and 16 GB RAM. I have a route which calls the HttpBin API. When i launch load testing with Constant throughput of 25 tps, i am getting around 0.75% 502 (Bad Gate way) errors.
What might be the issue.

I tried increasing the Netty's worker Thread count to 200, but no change in the throughput. still getting around 0.75% 502 errors.

Update:- After upgrading Spring Cloud Gateway version to 4.0.0, the 502 error count is reduced. It is now 0.15% 502 errors.

Comment: What is the result if you update to the latest releases?

Comment: after upgrading to gateway 4.0.0, still getting 0.15% 502 errors